# Drill Down based on parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have a report with a multi value parameter and drill downs. When the report opens the drill downs are collapsed. I would like for the drill downs to be expanded if one parameter only has one value.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have dropdowns expanded by default. There's no equivalent to a milti-line textbox.